# It's hip to be squ4re

Tags: cipher

My friend came up to me and said he had a question for me. He then handed me this note and asked me to reply in one line (whatever that's supposed to mean).

> Sidbmuaca jg Ztctmedte, xoeh zeuh ele mafj knp pnib iufe dudbhs simlzi?

What should I tell my friend?

**Hint #1:**

> My friend called and said that the title of the question he gave me is actually two hints.

**Hint #2:**

> Just got an E-Mail from my friend saying that the way he wants me to answer is a third hint.

**Hint #3:**

> Aside from being an occasionally cryptic jerk, my friend claims to be a lyricist.

**Hint #4:**

> My friend just dropped by to give me another hint. Apparently The first letter that's missing in the question is supposed to stay missing (alphabetically of course)

**Hint #5:**

> I wish he'd told me sooner, apparently the way he told me to answer was backwards...

Comment: Should the title be squ4re instead?

Comment: @GordonAllocman for some reason I forgot there was an "a" in that word lol

Comment: I know the cipher used but I have no idea how to actually decode the message and if I am right about the cipher the possible keyspace is $25!^4 \approx 5.7887 · 10^{100}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from Gordon Allocman, using his helpful tool

> [Four-Square decoder](http://www.geocachingtoolbox.com/index.php?page=fourSquareCipher)
>  I entered the first two lines of the lyrics from "It's Hip To Be Square" as the keys.
>  They are:
>  "I used to be a renegade"
>  "I used to fool around"

Using hint #4

> There is no "Q" in the question, so select the option to skip Q in the tool.

And I got the following result:

> According to Wikipedia, what year did this pop rock band become active?

To which the answer is:

> [A new group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huey_Lewis_and_the_News) was formed in 1978 under the name "Huey Lewis & The American Express". They changed their name the following year to "Huey Lewis and the News"

Comment: Correct. That is indeed the right answer.

Comment: Just for the sake of proper attribution, I did not make the tool, just found it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer of info I have determined so far:

The cipher is a

> [Four-square cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-square_cipher) as hinted by the title

The title may be a reference to:

> [Hip to be square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip_to_Be_Square) the song

About hint #2:

> Reply in one line might be a clue to determining the key for the cipher, or maybe the song is a hint, or maybe both together will lead to the key

About hint #3:

> Key is maybe hidden in the song lyrics to the song previously mentioned

About hint #4:

> Using the tool (or however you are decoding it) skip the letter A. I still can't get a hit with any lyrics from the song yet

Helpful tool:

> [Four-Square decoder](http://www.geocachingtoolbox.com/index.php?page=fourSquareCipher)

Comment: You're on the right track

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with this cipher or how to go about solving it, so I might have to just pass the torch to someone else

Comment: The tool you found will definitely get you the answer my friend wants. You just need to figure what his key is... My friend is way too cryptic sometimes...

Comment: I have tried pretty much all the lines of that song as the key but no success